# Sound issues after upgrading Kubuntu to 20.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, kubuntu, 20.10

I upgraded Kubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10. After this sound often doesn't work when booting my computer, it gets fixed if I restart the X-server with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

I tried making a fresh OS install but the issue persists.

Does anyone know what might be the issue? It's rather annoying to have to quit all GUI apps to get sound to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar (same?) problem after upgrading my Kubuntu installation to 20.10. The cause was Pipewire, which got installed in the upgrade.

The solution, for me, was to disable the Pipewire service:

```sh
sudo systemctl --global disable pipewire
sudo systemctl reboot
```

That seemed to do the trick, but I ended up uninstalling the Pipewire binary, too:

```sh
sudo apt purge pipewire
```

P.S. [Pipewire](https://pipewire.org/) seems great in its promise! But I guess it still needs a bit more time to mature and to be properly integrated into the distribution(s).

Answer (score 0):

I too have a similar problem since upgrading to Kubuntu 20.10.  After each reboot, I have to enter audio settings, change the Built-In audio profile to something else, and then back to what was set and it works until the next restart.

I've also tried forcibly creating a new profile, as described below, but that was no help.

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse
```

killing PulseAudio and restarting

```
pulseaudio -k
```